# Dynamically prepend sub-menu item in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, function, navigation, submenu

How would I best go about adding an item to the beginning of the sub-menu?

I figured out a way on how to add an item to the beginning of a normal navigation using the below code, but unsure on how to go about specifying how to add this to a sub-menu.

```
function addMenuItem($items, $args) {
    if( $args->theme_location == 'header-menu' ) {
        $hithere = '<li class="hithere">Hi</li>';
        $newmenu = $hithere . $items;
    return $newmenu;
    } 
}
```

Is there a best practice way on how to go about doing this?

Thanks in advance for any help.